# Paypal shipment details

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am using PayPal Adaptive payments (chained payments).

If I set:
1. CREATE payment
2. In the SetPaymentOptions -> Requires shipping address selection = true
3. When I redirect user for the https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr&cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=[PA KEY] user after authentication is not shown any prompt for shipping address

why?

Accordingly to the

https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/pay-api-operation

when using CREATE I should do: CREATE – Use this option to set up the payment instructions with SetPaymentOptions and then execute the payment at a later time with the ExecutePayment.

But as soon as I try to run ExecutePayment I get the following information:

> > This payment request must be authorized by the sender

How can I set additional payment options then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ExecutePayment call would only be used if you're utilizing delayed chained payments.  Otherwise, the payment still happens as soon as the buyer logs in and approves it, so there is no need for ExecutePayment.  Calling it at that point results in the error you're getting, that the paykey was already used.

Comment: I got response form Paypal, and they say Execute payment should work, but not in sandbox. For some strange reason this doesn't work correctly in sandbox :)

Comment: It looks like you've edited the original question, so my answer looks a little misleading now.  When calling Pay with CREATE you can use SetPaymentOptions, but you still don't need ExecutePayment unless you're working with delayed chained payments.  Otherwise, the payment will happen as soon as the user reviews and submits the order on the PayPal pages.

Comment: delayed are only for delayed payment for the next chained person.

Comment: All I need is a queue of payments that I can execute one by one whenever I want to. So my current best option is:

1. Get the preapprovals
2. Execute payments

Comment: Ok, well in that case you still don't need delayed chained payments. You can simply use the Preapproval API to create a profile for the payer which will return a PreapprovalKey back to you.  Then when you make your Pay call you simply include that Preapproval key.  The payment will take place without any redirection at that point since the user already preapproved it.  You can trigger as many payments as the profile will allow based on how you set it up.

Comment: and that's what I currently use :)

Answer (score 1):

Did the sender actually authorize the payment?
The flow should be like:

1. Call Pay API operation with `actionType` as CREATE
2. If `paymentExecStatus`=CREATED and `ack`=SUCCESS, obtain `payKey` (here, keep `detailLevel`=`ReturnAll` in `RequestEnvelope` field of your Pay API request)
3. Redirect user to Paypal https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=YOUR_PAYKEY_ABOVE
4. If user approves payment, you will be redirected to your returnURL sent as a part of Pay API request
5. Verify approval status using PaymentDetails API operation
6. Later you can execute the payment thus setup in step 4 using ExecutePayment API operation. Send the same `payKey` you obtained in step 2.

You have got error code 550001 since the user approval seems to be not yet done successfully. It may be due to: 
The application did not redirect user/sender to Paypal for authorization

OR

The user did not enter correct login details

OR

There were not sufficient funds available
etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
1.done
2. done
3.done
4.done
5.done
6. the money is already on my account. If I try to do the execute payment I receive the following message: payKey AP-xxxxx has already been used to make a payment

so what is CREATE used for? and still I don't know how to make user pick the shipment details

Comment: What is more strange, in the SDK examples there is Execute payment option available only if these conditions are met:

} else if(($_POST['preapprovalKey'] != null ) && ($_POST['actionType'] == "CREATE") && ($response->paymentExecStatus == "CREATED" )) {

so in the SDK totally differs from the DOCS available in the developer section

Comment: Regarding your second comment, please explain how do you find the code portion you pasted `if(($_POST['preapprovalKey'] != null ) && ($_POST['actionType'] == "CREATE") && ($response->paymentExecStatus == "CREATED" ))` different from the docs? As far as I can see it is correct.

Comment: Regarding the first comment, try executing PaymentDetails API with the same payKey and see what you get in the `actionType` and `status` fields of the response object.

Comment: Zeeshan: regarding SDK and DOCS: In the docs it's stated that CREATE should be used if we want to use setpaymentoptions. While it doesn't state anything about the preapproval, which is checked in this case.

Regarding first comment: Before user acceptance: 
    [actionType] => CREATE
    [status] => CREATED

After acceptance:

    [actionType] => CREATE
    [status] => COMPLETED

So now the only question is: how can I actually use the ExecutePayment API?

Comment: Now I am really confused.

I got this response from paypal when I asked why after user accepts payment that had CREATE type, it is set to COMPLETED state:


"As I said, once the PayKey is approved, you're authorized to transfer the funds with the ExecutePayment API Call. The behavior in the sandbox is not what we're expecting to see."


But from what some people say it is the way it should be :) 

I will create production account, create payment and test it